# I am trying to find a better/easier way to count alphabetic characters in a file or shell variable

Tags: shell, command-line, grep

I have a file containing the following text:

```
we are going to write something 1 2 3
```

`wc` tells me I have 1 line 9 words and 38 characters.

I'm looking to count the 26 letters only (`a-z`, no numbers or white spaces etc).

Here's my current solution:

```
grep -o [[:alpha:]] filename | wc -l
```

I really want to know if there is a "better" way to do this at the command line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would delete all non-alpha characters using `tr` and count the number of resultant characters. Passing both the `tr` solution and your solution to `bash`'s `time` built-in suggests the `tr` solution is about 5 times faster, at least on my system

```
tr -cd '[:alpha:]' <filename | wc -m
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `awk` for figure out this too !

```
awk '{c+=gsub(s,s)}END{print c}' s='[[:alpha:]]' filename
```

Comment: While your solution clearly answers the question, one-to-two-line answers are often not that helpful. Consider expanding your answer to include documentation or futher explanation of your proposed solution.

Comment: @HalosGhost.   I disagree.  Unless asked by the OP, a concise reply is perfectly acceptable.

Comment: @fpmurphy1, what I wrote is a commonly held opinion on this site (and SE, at large), not a personal view.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
LC_ALL=C grep -o [[:alpha:]] | sort -u | wc -l
```

Change `LC_ALL=C.UTF-8` or your locale to match your own language `[a-zA-Z]`.

Comment: No, that gives 12, not 26. Why the unique? (I assume the sort is to allow unique?)

Comment: Because that the OP wants. How many letters in alphabeta ( total 26 letters)

Comment: Oh... I was sure the 26 is refering to the simple count of characters in the input when non-letters are ignored. "wearegoingtowritesomething" are 26, right? Looks like it's a really bad example...