# What is the easiest way to count the amount of letters in a string entered

Tags: shell-script, string

I am currently writing a program in the raspberry pi that will allow a user to enter a string, and have the program count the amount of letters in it. I am looking into `expr` but I don't know how to use it, and what this actually does. Could you let me know what this means and how I can use it for my program.

This is what I currently have.

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Enter a word."
read str
"help here please!"
```

Thanks

Comment: Maybe you should ask the teacher if you're struggling with the homework!

Comment: You don't need to use `expr` since this will fork another process thus occupy more resources. It is as simple as `echo "${#str}"`

Comment: Do you want to count characters or bytes? Some languages have multibyte characters.

Comment: I would like to count the characters in the string entered by the user.

Comment: Related: [Having a problem with a shell script counting characters](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/156229/80216), [Number of characters in a shell command's output](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/160497/80216), and [Trying to find a better way to count letters in a file or shell variable](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/156571/80216).

Answer (score 1):

You could use this

```
expr length $str
```

Hopefully this should help!

Comment: This, I have found, is a very longwinded answer compared to what val0x00ff has suggested. I much prefer to use what he has said as it makes things a lot easier. Thanks

Comment: OK maybe next time, you decide whether you want to use 'expr' or not. Make it a bit clearer